# Principal value integral of complex exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, lebesgue-integral, proof-explanation, cauchy-principal-value

I'm reading the article [Brownian distance covariance](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoas/1267453933) and stumbled upon a equality I can't seem to derive myself. We are first presented with the following lemma:

[image]

and after stating this lemma, the authors follow up with a remark in which my problem lies:
[image]

Now the first two integrals are rather simple to show using the above lemma but the third iterated principal value integral is where my troubles begin.

I have tried multiple approaches so far, two of them being to rewrite the nominator:
$$
1-\exp(it^\intercal x + i s^\intercal y) = (1-\exp(it^\intercal x)) + (1-\exp(is^\intercal y)) -(1-\exp(it^\intercal x))(1-\exp(is^\intercal y))
$$
but this approach yields nothing since the second term yields a the inner principal value integral of $\infty$ and vice versa for the first term when evaluating the outer principal value integral. Another approach I tried was to write
\begin{align*}
1-\exp(it^\intercal x + i s^\intercal y) =& 1- \cos(t^\intercal x + s^t y) -i\sin (t^\intercal x + s^\intercal y) \\
 =& 1- \cos t^\intercal x \cos s^\intercal y + \sin t^\intercal x \sin s^\intercal y -i (\sin t^\intercal x \cos s^\intercal y + \cos t^\intercal x \sin s^\intercal y) \\
 =&(1-\cos t^\intercal x) + (1- \cos s^\intercal y)-(1-\cos t^\intercal x)(1-\cos s^\intercal y) \\ 
&+ \sin t^\intercal x \sin s^\intercal y -i (\sin t^\intercal x \cos s^\intercal y + \cos t^\intercal x \sin s^\intercal y) \\
\end{align*}
In this expression the third term integrates to the negative value of the wanted solution, so its close but not the wanted expression (even if I ignore the sign, I can't get the other terms to yield a zero integral).

Am approaching this is the wrong way or is there something I have missed? Any solutions/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: I reposted this question on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/241830/interpretation-of-a-singular-integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with the last equality. Consider a set $A\subset\mathbb{R^q}$ where  $\left<s,Y \right>$ is bounded away from integer multiples of $2\pi$. For $t$ in a  small enough neighborhood of the origin, call it $B$, the numerator is bounded away from $0$. So the singularity is not canceled out. Hence, for $s\in A$ the integral

\begin{equation*}
\int_B 
\frac{1-\exp\{i\left<t,X \right>+ i\left<s,Y \right>   \}}
{|t|_p^{1+p} |s|_q^{1+q}}
dt
\end{equation*}
is not defined (or infinite). This implies
\begin{equation*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^p}
\frac{1-\exp\{i\left<t,X \right>+ i\left<s,Y \right>   \}}
{|t|_p^{1+p} |s|_q^{1+q}}
dt
\end{equation*}
is not defined (or infinite).

The inner integral must be defined a.e. for convergence, and this is not the case.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, the numerator has a zero at $(t , s) = (0,0)$, and they probably meant $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^p \times\mathbb{R}^q} \ldots dt ds$

Comment: The denominator is zero at other points. You have to control the singularities everywhere. Also if it isnt integrable on a subset, it isnt integrable on the larger set.

Comment: what I mean is that you didn't prove the integral diverges

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify the answer of Dunham, take the easy example with $Y = 0$, which I develop on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/a/262180/104877). Both reassuring and puzzling in the same time, this results is given but actually *never used* in the "Brownian distance covariance" paper. Even more puzzling, the same equality was already given, without being used either, in the earlier paper on [distance covariance](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aos/1201012979).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, much appreciated.